# BLE Communication - Can't collect statistics of sensor use

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

All Running apps receive the sensors data through BLE.

it means that the sensor connects directly to the 3rd app and i can't collect any statistics of sensor use.

Here are my questions:

1. Do you have an idea for a solution for it? How I can collect statistics?
2. Can I build an app that receives the data from the sensor and communicates with the running apps through BLE, both my app and running app on the same mobile device?

   In simple words, can the running app receives BLE transmission from another app in same device?

Comment: Reviewed the title to make the issue more obvious, enhanced formatting and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what your goal really is, but anyway from a technical point of view here is how it works:

In both Android and iOS, multiple apps can be connected to the same peripheral. But if one app issues a GATT request, the response will be delivered to only that app. Both apps can also register for notifications/indications. When a notification/indication is received, it is sent to all apps that are registered for notifications/indications. There is no way for the peripheral to know which app a GATT request comes from since they all appear to be sent from the same client.